# Complex background not working with background-size cover

Tags: css

I have a relatively complex background I'm trying to do with both a linear gradient and image. Now with this background, the background-size: cover feature does not seem to work.

Here's my CSS and HTML

```
<style>
#main:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(57deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.47),rgba(0,0,0,0.47)) 0% 0% / cover, url(https://cdn.hyax.com/d946b765-bc74-47eb-8881-0c4211d9b307/-/preview/2000x2000/-/quality/lighter/-/format/auto/null) repeat center center fixed;
}
</style>

<div id="main">

</div>
```

When the window stretches beyond the size of the image, the "background size cover" does not cover the image.

Is there a fix to help with this particular instance?

I have a JSfiddle also - https://jsfiddle.net/beamertravis/x8q3we6r/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified `cover` only for `linear-gradient` but you didn't do that for `url` part (part after comma). You have to put `cover` into the second part of your background (after `url`) or use `background-size: cover;` alone for both of them.

```css
#main:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(57deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.47),rgba(0,0,0,0.47)) 0% 0% / cover, url(https://cdn.hyax.com/d946b765-bc74-47eb-8881-0c4211d9b307/-/preview/2000x2000/-/quality/lighter/-/format/auto/null) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<main id="main"></main>
```

Comment: Yep this was it!